# Ordered attributes in retrieving documents from mongo with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

When I store the following document into mongo, something like:

```
{
name: Somename,
profile: Someprofile
}
```

When I use a find_one():

I get a result of something like:

```
{
profile: Someprofile,
_id: 35353432326532(random mongo id),
name: Somename
}
```

Is there some way in python such that when I do something before or after find_one such that I can get a result in a json string that is ordered like:

```
{
_id: 35353432326532(random mongo id),
name: Somename,
profile: Someprofile
}
```

I tried using an OrderedDict like below, but it does not seem to help.

```
somedocument = db.mycollection
theordereddict = OrderedDict(data_layer.find_one())
print str(theordereddict)
```

How do I get my output string in the right order in regards to attributes? Is this order dictated by something else before I even insert the document into the database?

Comment: what is the reason you want to rely on the order of fields in JSON doc? since they are named, you can reference them by the key names and not worry about the order...

Comment: good reading: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52306-to-sort-a-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

`collections.OrderedDict` doesn't order keys it just *preserves* order, you need to insert keys into it in the order you want to retrieve them.

```
d = data_layer.find_one()
def key_function(tuple):
    """This defines the sort order for the sorted builtin"""
    return tuple[0]
sorted_dict = collections.OrderedDict((k,v) for k, v in sorted(d.items(),
                                                               key=key_function))
```

That said, it looks like `print str(sorted_dict)` doesn't give you the output you want.  I think you need to build your sorted string representation manually.  E.g.:

```
s = "{" + ",".join(["%s:%s" for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=key_function)]) + "}"
```

Comment: What is the "lambda" and the syntax after it mean?

Comment: `lambda` defines an anonymous function that is the equivalent of `key_function` in my updated answer.  The important part is using a function to customize the sort performed by the `sorted` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same as @Mike Steder's answer but maybe less fancy and more clear:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

theordereddict = OrderedDict()
d = data_layer.find_one()
for k in sorted(d.keys()):
    theordereddict[k] = d[k]

json.dumps(theordereddict)
```